# A typed list as return type in an abstract method returns a list of objects - why?

Tags: java, list, generics, abstract-class, abstract-methods

I'm confused - and need help. I've an abstract class with an abstract method:

```
public abstract class AbstractA<T extends SomeOtherClass> {

    public abstract List<String> getAll();

}
```

When I declare a method parameter of type AbstractA and call getAll() the IDE shows me the correct return type (`List<String>`).

```
...

public void test(AbstractA abstractA) {
    abstractA.getAll(); // <- returns List<String>
}

...
```

But when I want to iterate over that list, each element is of type Object and not String:

```
...

public void test(AbstractA abstractA) {
    for(String element : abstractA.getAll()) {  // <- compile error: 
     // error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String
    }
}

...
```

And it gets even better:

```
...

public void test(AbstractA abstractA) {
    List<String> myElements = abstractA.getAll();
    for(String element : myElements) { // <- this is correct!
    }
}

...
```

I've no idea what's going on here. I'am using Java 8 (update 25). 
Can anyone explain to me why the compiler did not accept an iteration over my list?

I really appreciate your help.

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: I'm almost certain your `AbstractA` type is generic.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ... and somewhere he used `AbstractA` as the type instead of `AbstractA<String>` (so, I agree with you). Daniel, can you post your real code, please?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But why is that important? 
I will update my question.

Comment: @Daniel: If `AbstractA` is generic, then you have to provide the generic type, or else the compiler will the use the most basic class instead: `Object`.

Comment: But the generic type of my class has nothing to do with my list.

Comment: Is it `List<String> getAll()` or `List<T> getAll()`?

Comment: It does because you are using a raw type `AbstractA`, which is the erasure of `AbstractA`, so that `getAll` also returns a raw type `List`.

Comment: It is List<String> not List<T>. The generic type of my class has nothing to do with that list.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. When I change my method parameter to **public void test(AbstractA<?> abstractA)** the compile error is gone. But still, I can't say why, because the generic type of the class has nothing to do with that list.

Comment: @Daniel Read Radiodefs comment and read something about `erasure` :). ([this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) for example)

Comment: _Rawness_ applies to **any** generic usage, not only those that use declared type variables.